# Need to be able to call the `attachInternals` method

Tags: svelte

I am compiling the svelte components to web components and for some components I to be able to call the `attachInternals()` method on the `HTMLElement` instance. Since the `SvelteElement` class extends the `HTMLElelement` class calling the `attachInternals()` method seems like it would be easy, but it seems like there is no `this` reference to do so.

Does anyone know how, or if, this can be done?

Comment: Why do you need to call `attachInternals`, what is your *real* goal here?

Comment: I need to call the `setFormValue()` on the `internals` reference to allow the component to have it's value be bound to a parent form element.

Comment: If you want to use that method you will also have to set a static property `formAssociated` on the element class, as far as I know. This also does not seem easily supported. In general, custom elements/their support is not that great, so I hope using them is really worth it to you....

Comment: Svelte has been ok for web component development, but some of the component are missing the form binding ability; which would be nice to provide. It seems like something that would be rather simple to implement on the svelte side.

Comment: Consider opening an issue for this if there isn't one already. Though there is quite a backlog and the web component part of Svelte seems to not be a priority either.